# Export files with folder structure in Evernote

Tags: evernote

Is there a way we can export files from Evernote, in the same folder/notebook/stack structure.

For eg: I have a Notebook "QUERIES" and multiple stacks (STACK1...etc.) inside it. Each stack will have notes. When exporting, I would the notes to be exported into folders like `QUERIES > STACK1 > note 1, note 2` etc..

But on export, it just downloads all files into one target folder.

Answer (score 1):

Backupery for Evernote can do this: https://www.backupery.com/products/backupery-for-evernote/ The app preserves Notebook/Stack structure when exports the data from Evernote. Also you could select which exact notebooks to export.